# How to use declare_parameters with a vector of floats?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros2 source build master branch. I was trying

```
 this->declare_parameters<std::vector<float>>("foo", { {"bar", {1.2}},{ {"zee", {4.2}}});
```

but that fails with

```
/home/usr/ros2_foxy/install/rclcpp_lifecycle/include/rclcpp_lifecycle/lifecycle_node_impl.hpp:144:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘rclcpp::ParameterValue::get<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >() const’
  144 |   ).get<ParameterT>();
```

Is there currently a way to specify a list of parameters which have vectors as their values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373405/how-to-use-declare_parameters-with-a-vector-of-floats?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not implemented for floats, just change the syntax to double and it works.

```
this->declare_parameters<std::vector<double>>("foo", {
            {"bar", {1.2}},
});
```

and get the config with

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> foo;
this->get_parameters("foo", foo);
```

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1